# SEM: Converting Mplus syntax to lavaan for model specification

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I am trying to translate a model syntax from Mplus to lavaan. The syntax is from an [article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5568008/).

Mplus syntax snippet:

```
!Defining the change in Y as a function of Y1 and Y2;
deltay BY y2@1;
deltay;
[deltay];
y2 on y1@1;
y2 with y1@0;
y2@0;
[y2@0 y1];
```

Translated to lavaan with `lavaan::mplus2lavaan.modelSyntax()` yields:

```
#Defining the change in Y as a function of Y1 and Y2
deltay =~ 1*y2
deltay ~~ deltay
deltay ~ 1
y2 ~ 1*y1
y2 ~~ 0*y1
0*y2 ~~ 0*y2
y2 ~ 0*1
y1 ~ 1
```

However, I am quite sure I made a mistake because when I run the full model (not provided here) I get an error:

> Error in lavData(data = data, group = group, cluster = cluster,
>   ov.names = OV.NAMES, : lavaan ERROR: data object of class function
>
> In addition: Warning messages: 1: In lavParseModelString(model) :
>   lavaan WARNING: left-hand side of formula below contains modifier:
>   0*y2~~0*y2

If I leave out the `0*y2~~0*y2` specification, it runs well. I am not sure what `0*y2~~0*y2` signifies or if the translation is correct or not.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `y2~~0*y2` to fix the variance of `y2` at zero. Double-check it does what you want in the output